# Unable to create a collection in MongoDb atlas using Django RestApi framework

Tags: django, database, mongodb, rest, djongo

So basically i created a new `Django` project and an app which contains my model.
I have already created a free cluster on mongoDb atlas and connected my project via Djongo engine.

**Issues:**

when i first made make migrations and then migrated my model , it created a new database from scratch since i had not created it.
however my model name is `Mtsdata` and would like to create a corresponding collection. why is the collection not created though it shows in the migration files that i have created the model and also in my database , my `django_migrations` is updated ?

```
from django.db import models

class Mtsdata(models.Model):
Company = models.CharField(max_length= 32 , null=True, blank=True)
plant = models.CharField(max_length= 32 , null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "Mtsdata"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from interndata import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('mtsdata/',views.Mtsdatalist.as_view()),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Mtsdata
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, ListAPIView
# Create your views here.

class Mtsdatalist(ListAPIView):
    
    def get(self,request):
        queryset = Mtsdata.objects.all()
      
        return Response(queryset.values())
```